# kodi waiting for external storage

Tags: android, kodi

I've been getting the **`waiting for external`** storage message in Kodi on Android 4.2.2, and now it doesn't start (Kodi version 14.2 Helix) After some logcat debugging, I found this on the messages:

```
D/Kodi ( 6945): External storage = /mnt/sdcard; state = unmounted
```

But when I check the /mnt/sdcard path it exists and it is mounted.

And I might think this is because of the way kodi checks for the path. I've changed the **xbmc.data** path in the **xbmc_env.properties** file located at the **/sdcard** folder to:

```
xbmc.data=/data/kodi_data_files
xbmc.data=/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.xbmc.kodi/files
xbmc.data=/sdcard/Android/data/org.xbmc.kodi/files
```

But not success so far. Any ideas?

Comment: How about uninstall, run any updates, then reinstall the app. I had a similar problem and it took those steps to get the app reconfigured and recalibrated. It worked!

Comment: Check this thread if it helps: http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=208089

Answer (score 0):

It is probably looking for a previously connected USB drive or SD Card. 
Either plug the drive in or Go into Settings>Storage and select the drive which is missing and not required. Inside select forget drive / storage.  This worked for me.